# CFileException::sharingViolation on opening executable with compiled /clr

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli

My legacy MFC application opens its own executable for reading (to compute its hash code to make tampering harder). To do so, it uses

```
CFile f( sExecFileName, CFile::modeRead | CFile::typeBinary );
```

This line starts throwing an `CFileException` with couse `CFileException::sharingViolation` when I compile the application, or even a small part of it not containing this code, with the /clr flag.  This behavior occurs only if I compile "Debug" instead of "Release", but even without attached debugger. What causes this and how do I fix it?

Disclaimer: My C++ is almost as good as my chinese (and I am not from China). Sorry if this question is trivial.

Comment: CFile::shareDenyNone is required.  Do ask yourself if this feature is worth the trouble.  Checking the hash *after* you started running the program is *too late*.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it. And I'd rather drop that "feature" but that is not in my control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Hand Passant in the comment, I was missing `CFile::shareDenyNone`.